# Translating R to Python, Problems running regression

Tags: python, r, regression, replication

My regression won't run. It tells me

> > > model = PanelOLS.from_formula(formula, data=subset_bf2017, entity_effects=True)
> > > TypeError: from_formula() got an unexpected keyword argument 'entity_effects'
>
> > > model = RandomEffects.from_formula(formula, data=subset_bf2017)
> > > FactorEvaluationError: Unable to evaluate factor `log_GJSI`. [KeyError: 'log_GJSI']

I am trying to run a subset of my data, but it tells me that there is something wrong with my data. All the variables should be in the subset. I am trying to take R code and replicate it using python.

```
# del 1

# Uncomment to install packages needed for this file:
!pip install pandas
!pip install matplotlib
!pip install statsmodels
!pip install linearmodels
!pip install pyreadstat
!pip install datetime

from linearmodels.panel import RandomEffects
from linearmodels.panel import PanelOLS
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels.api as sm
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pyreadstat
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# New functions
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# function for reverse cumulative sum of vector
# summing up from end to start
def revcumsum(x):
    return x[::-1].cumsum()[::-1]

# function to calculate standard errors of cumulative sum
def secumsum(vcov):
    L = vcov.shape[0]
    se = []
    for i in range(1, L+1):
        a = [1] * i
        V = a @ vcov.iloc[0:i, 0:i] @ a
        se.append(V**0.5)
    return se

# function to calculate standard errors of reverse cumulative sum
# summing up from end to start
def serevcumsum(vcov):
    L = vcov.shape[0]
    se = []
    for i in range(L, 0, -1):
        a = [1] * (L-i+1)
        V = a @ vcov.iloc[i-1:L, i-1:L] @ a
        se.append(V**0.5)
    return se

#Read data
bf2017, _ = pyreadstat.read_dta("C:/Users/tormo/Econometrics using R/bf2017.dta")

# create period variable from year and month in R 'yearmon' format
bf2017["yearmonth"] = pd.to_datetime(bf2017["year"].astype(str) + bf2017["month"].astype(str),format = "%Y%m")

# tror denne er helt meningsløs. skjønner ikke hvorfor dette må være med i det heletatt.
#bf2017 = bf2017[["state", "state_abb", "year", "month","GJSI", "PBD", "population", "insured_employment", "cont_claims", "init_claims", "employment", "labor_force", "unemployment", "wage" ]]


#her lages det bare en variabel som skal inn i matrisen
# create covariate used in Baker and Fradkin (2017)
bf2017['frac_total_ui'] = (bf2017['cont_claims'] + bf2017['init_claims']) / bf2017['population']
print(bf2017.columns)


# tror ikke dette vil fungere i python
# define data as panel data (plm package)
# states are cross-section, yearmonth are periods
# Set the index of bf2017 DataFrame to 'state' and 'yearmonth' columns
#bf2017.set_index([, 'yearmonth'], inplace=True)
# Get the column names of bf2017 DataFrame
#colnames = bf2017.columns.tolist()
# Print the column names
# print(colnames)



# Convert the index to MultiIndex
# bf2017.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(bf2017.index)

# Sort the index if needed
# bf2017 = bf2017.sort_index()


# riktig frem til her.
# må se på hva som må gjøres nedover men begynner å se noe mer lovende ut
# deretter begynne å legge inn lag på variabler i matrisen


# create treatment adoption indicator
# increase by at least 13 weeks
bf2017['D_PBD_incr'] = bf2017['PBD'].diff().where(lambda x:x>=13, 0).astype(int)
# replace missing first treatment with zero (implicitly assumed by BF2017)
bf2017['D_PBD_incr'] = bf2017['D_PBD_incr'].fillna(0)

# create 3 leads 
bf2017['F3_D_PBD_incr'] = bf2017['D_PBD_incr'].shift(-3) 
bf2017['F2_D_PBD_incr'] = bf2017['D_PBD_incr'].shift(-2) 
bf2017['F1_D_PBD_incr'] = bf2017['D_PBD_incr'].shift(-1) 

# create 4 lags
bf2017['L1_D_PBD_incr'] = bf2017['D_PBD_incr'].shift(-1)
bf2017['L2_D_PBD_incr'] = bf2017['D_PBD_incr'].shift(-2)
bf2017['L3_D_PBD_incr'] = bf2017['D_PBD_incr'].shift(-3)
bf2017['L4_D_PBD_incr'] = bf2017['D_PBD_incr'].shift(-4)

# replace missing lags with zero (implicitly assumed by BF2017)
bf2017['L1_D_PBD_incr'] = bf2017['L1_D_PBD_incr'].fillna(0)
bf2017['L2_D_PBD_incr'] = bf2017['L2_D_PBD_incr'].fillna(0)
bf2017['L3_D_PBD_incr'] = bf2017['L3_D_PBD_incr'].fillna(0)
bf2017['L4_D_PBD_incr'] = bf2017['L4_D_PBD_incr'].fillna(0)



# Making a variable for GJSI with log
bf2017['log_GJSI'] = np.log(bf2017['GJSI'])

# Create a new DataFrame with the selected columns
subset_bf2017 = bf2017.loc[bf2017['year'] <= 2011]

# Calculate log_GJSI column
subset_bf2017.loc[:, 'log_GJSI'] = pd.to_numeric(subset_bf2017['log_GJSI'], errors='coerce')
subset_bf2017 = subset_bf2017.dropna(subset=['log_GJSI'])

# Define the formula for the fixed effects model
formula = 'log_GJSI ~ F3_D_PBD_incr + F2_D_PBD_incr + F1_D_PBD_incr + D_PBD_incr + L1_D_PBD_incr + L2_D_PBD_incr + L3_D_PBD_incr + L4_D_PBD_incr + frac_total_ui + C(yearmonth)'

# Fit the fixed effects model
model = PanelOLS.from_formula(formula, data=subset_bf2017, entity_effects=True)
model = RandomEffects.from_formula(formula, data=subset_bf2017)

# Estimate the model
results = model.fit()

# Print the summary statistics
print(results)

print(subset_bf2017.columns)
print(subset_bf2017['log_GJSI'].dtype)
print(subset_bf2017.head())
print(subset_bf2017.isnull().sum())

print(subset_bf2017.dtypes)
```

[The paper that I try replicating the results of using python](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3571164)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).